# sequential CSS transforms don't match manually computed 3x3 matrix?

Tags: css, matrix, transform

When I apply several sequential transformations to an element using css3's `transform`, I don't get the same computed matrix as when I multiply the transform matrices by hand. They are significantly different for some reason. Why?

Here's a demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfqhw64q/7/

Here's the same demo with larger diffs:

http://jsfiddle.net/dfqhw64q/6/

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

figured it out.

the matrices i was using for skew are actually shear matrices that expect linear values, not angles. after changing `skewX`,`skewY` to `Math.tan(skewX)`,`Math.tan(skewY)`, everything aligned.

Works:
http://jsfiddle.net/dfqhw64q/8/